# LeetCode: Insert delete getrandom o1 C#

Tags: c#, interview-questions

https://leetcode.com/problems/insert-delete-getrandom-o1/

please comment on performance

> Implement the RandomizedSet class:
>
> bool insert(int val) Inserts an item val into the set if not present.
> Returns true if the item was not present, false otherwise. bool
> remove(int val) Removes an item val from the set if present. Returns
> true if the item was present, false otherwise. int getRandom() Returns
> a random element from the current set of elements (it's guaranteed
> that at least one element exists when this method is called). Each
> element must have the same probability of being returned. Follow up:
> Could you implement the functions of the class with each function
> works in average O(1) time?
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input ["RandomizedSet", "insert", "remove", "insert", "getRandom",
> "remove", "insert", "getRandom"] [[], [1], [2], [2], [], [1], [2], []]
> Output [null, true, false, true, 2, true, false, 2]
>
> Explanation RandomizedSet randomizedSet = new RandomizedSet();
> randomizedSet.insert(1); // Inserts 1 to the set. Returns true as 1
> was inserted successfully. randomizedSet.remove(2); // Returns false
> as 2 does not exist in the set. randomizedSet.insert(2); // Inserts 2
> to the set, returns true. Set now contains [1,2].
> randomizedSet.getRandom(); // getRandom() should return either 1 or 2
> randomly. randomizedSet.remove(1); // Removes 1 from the set, returns
> true. Set now contains [2]. randomizedSet.insert(2); // 2 was already
> in the set, so return false. randomizedSet.getRandom(); // Since 2 is
> the only number in the set, getRandom() will always return 2.
>
> Constraints:
>
> \$-2^{31} <= val <= 2^{31} - 1\$. At most \$10^5\$ calls will be made to insert, remove, and getRandom. There will be at least one element in the data
> structure when getRandom is called.

```
public class RandomizedSet {
    
     private HashSet<int> _set;
        /** Initialize your data structure here. */
        public RandomizedSet()
        {
            _set = new HashSet<int>();
        }

        /** Inserts a value to the set. Returns true if the set did not already contain the specified element. */
        public bool Insert(int val)
        {
            if (_set.Contains(val))
            {
                return false;
            }
            _set.Add(val);
            return true;
        }

        /** Removes a value from the set. Returns true if the set contained the specified element. */
        public bool Remove(int val)
        {
            if (_set.Contains(val))
            {
                _set.Remove(val);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /** Get a random element from the set. */
        public int GetRandom()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int key = rand.Next(_set.Count);
            return _set.ElementAt(key);
        }
}

/**
 * Your RandomizedSet object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * RandomizedSet obj = new RandomizedSet();
 * bool param_1 = obj.Insert(val);
 * bool param_2 = obj.Remove(val);
 * int param_3 = obj.GetRandom();
 */
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The `HashSet<int>` won't be changed hence make it `readonly`.
- Instead of calling `Contains()` prior to the call to `Add()`, if this evaluates to `false`, can be simplified to just `return _set.Add(val);` because the `Add()` method returns `false` if the value is allready in the `HashSet`. [Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=netcore-3.1)
- Instead of calling `Contains()` prior to calling `Remove()` can be simplified as well to just `return _set.Remove(val);` because `Remove()` will return `false` if the item isn't in the `HashSet`. [Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.remove?view=netcore-3.1)
- Calling `GetRandom()` in repeatedly short order  may result in the same element because the `Seed` of a created `Random` in .NET framework is based on the current timestamp. It is better to create a class-level `Random` to be used.

Summing up leads to

```
public class RandomizedSet {
    
    private readonly HashSet<int> _set;
    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    public RandomizedSet()
    {
        _set = new HashSet<int>();
    }

    /** Inserts a value to the set. Returns true if the set did not already contain the specified element. */
    public bool Insert(int val)
    {
        return _set.Add(val);
    }

    /** Removes a value from the set. Returns true if the set contained the specified element. */
    public bool Remove(int val)
    {
        return _set.Remove(val);
    }

    private readonly Random rand = new Random();
    /** Get a random element from the set. */
    public int GetRandom()
    {
        int key = rand.Next(_set.Count);
        return _set.ElementAt(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### `GetRandom()` Complexity

`HashSet<T>` does not support lookup by index so `ElementAt` needs to iterate until the requested element is reached. That requires O(n) steps not O(1).